# Default argument promotions in C cause error,but I don't know exactly why

Tags: c, types, parameters, casting, implicit-conversion

The following code example is from K. N. King's *C Programming.
A Modern Approach*.  It doesn't work properly: the output is `1` instead of `9`. The author says that this is a problem caused by the default parameter raising：

> At the time square is called, the compiler hasn’t seen a prototype yet, so it doesn’t know that square expects an argument of type `int`. Instead, the compiler performs the default argument promotions on `x`, with no effect. Since it’s expecting an argument of type `int` but has been given a `double` value instead,

But he doesn't give a very specific explanation, I'd like to know exactly how the problem occurs?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x = 3.0;
    printf("Square: %d\n", square(x));
    return 0;
}

int square(int n)
{
    return n * n;
}
```

I ran the program and it does not work, but I would like to know exactly what problem in the runtime is causing it.

Comment: In C a function or a prototype of the function must appear before a call in order for argument and return value conversion to  work as you'd normally expect. Here that's not true. The double argument is passed as-is  to the function that expects its argument to be an integer. double and int represent numbers very differently. Consequently, this program has "undefined behavior". Any decent compiler should emit at least one warning. Possibly several. With C, "warning" very often means "error." Until you understand exactly what you're doing, you should treat them as such.

Comment: @ll cool The problem is described in the provided quote by you.

Comment: K.N. King's second sentence is incorrect. No 'default argument promotions' were applied to `x`. It stayed as a `double`.

Comment: @user207421: The text says “the compiler performs the default argument promotions on x, with no effect.” That is correct. The default argument promotions are performed in this case, and the rules for the default argument promotions are that they leave a double as a double.

Answer (score 3):

The title first:

> Default argument promotions in C cause error ....

No, error is not caused by "default argument promotion".

The error is caused by compilers lack of knowledge about `square` when it's called. At that time the compiler doesn't know the type of argument expected by the function `square`.

Today such code is illegal (undefined behavior).

However, in the (not so) good old days, it was accepted (and some compilers still do). The rule was that the compiler should do "default argument promotion" on the arguments used in the function call. For instance, a `float` would be turned into a `double` before the call while a `short` would be turned into an `int`, etc.

For the posted code "default argument promotion" shall be applied but it has no effect as `x` is already a `double`. The compiler will just generate machine code for passing a `double`, i.e. `x` as it is. No conversion will take place.

The problem comes when the function `square` reads `n`. The function will assume that it was passed an `int` and the machine code will read the value in accordance with "**the rules for getting an `int` argument**".

And that's the key for this part of the question:

> ... I'd like to know exactly how the problem occurs?

It is about "call convention". A set of rules describing (among other things) how arguments are passed to a function. These conventions are **not** part of the C standard. Call convention is left as an "implementation thing". Different systems may do it in different ways. For instance Windows and Linux use different calling conventions.

So to find out "exactly  how the problem occurs?" you need to study the call convention for your specific system. There is no single explanation for it.

As an example consider System V ABI. Here the first floating point argument is passed using XMM0 and the first integer argument is passed using RDI. So for your code that implies that the caller will store the value `3.0` in XMM0 while the callee will read from RDI as it expects an integer. Obviously, that won't work.

On your system something different than the above may happen. But the common problem is the same: The caller and the callee are expecting different things, `double` versus `int`.

And even if some call convention specified the same "HW resource" for passing `double` and `int`, there would be other low level problems. The size of `double` and `int` may differ. The binary encoding of the flloating point value `3.0` is different from the binary encoding of the integer value `3`.

Comment: Do not conflate illegal and undefined. There are things in C that are undefined because the C committee expects them to be used with different behaviors in different implementations. They are not illegal. The C standard does not specify a complete programming language. It intentionally specifies a base language that is intended to be extended, and it leaves many things undefined so that the base language can be extended in different ways as suit people’s needs or desires.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code in the question is not valid C99, let alone C11, C18 or C23. In C99 and later, functions must be declared before they are used (except for main()). Only C90 allowed functions to be used without being declared - but that is not a standing standard and currently obsolete. You must declare the function before calling.

That said, the other problem in the given snippet is exactly what is mentioned in the quote, you are sending a `double` value when an `int` is expected. Since `double` and `int` are **not** [compatible types](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2), this program invokes undefined behaviour. The output cannnot be justified in any way.

Quoting C standard, chapter 6.5.2.2/P6

> *... If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (, ...) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined.*

If you need to know what is causing that *exact* output for a certain execution of the program, you need to refer to the documentation of the hardware and the compiler (and the running environment, as applicable) used in the process.

Comment: The code in the question is not valid C99, let alone C11, C18 or C23.  In C99 and later, functions must be declared before they are used (except for `main()`).  Only C90 allowed functions to be used without being declared — but only sloppy C code made use of that licence.  At the time the standard was created, there was a lot of code that now counts as sloppy.  In the 30+ years since then, that sloppiness has become less and less excusable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Absolutely sir, very important. I'll add a note.